# Magento on Nginx - Configuration

Tags: php, magento, nginx, tinymce

I'm working on an nginx.conf for running Magento, the site mostly works, magento is run using `php-fpm`.

But some parts of it are still not working, and I've tried every wiki, blog, etc around the web.

My problem is that where ever I have a Javascript pop-up on CMS pages and blocks, mainly the tiny_mce WYSIWYG editor, (/js/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage/image.htm etc) they open a `page not found`.

I don't know what should I do so this editor displays correctly.

Also, the downloader doesn't display.

It seems that each of these use its own index.php inside a different folder than root, so should I change the index to that?

like `$document_root/downloader/index.php` ?

Comment: It seems the SE network will always get in the way of people trying to help others in situations like this one. Frustrated users should consider posting to Webmasters or Serverfault when the Ivory Tower Brigade here comes along and closes useful information as off-topic. Oh, BTW, I just flagged this for reopening and it would seem moderators don't ever use nginx, so it must stay closed. :P

Comment: I am having the same issue, And im trying the answer below, but my question then is set on, where do we allow tinyimce - js to be read by nginx:

Answer (score 10):

I HIGHLY suggest you read and follow the [nginx primer by Martin Fjordvald](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/).

I use the following configuration for Magento. It not only works great, it also turns off access_log for images, etc. and has a special php-fpm configuration. Please note that the server root is specified within the server block. Several configuration files incorrectly specify it within a location block.

Magento nginx configuration file:
(Be sure to replace all paths and domain names accordingly)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 default ssl;
    server_name DOMAIN.COM;
    #rewrite requests to www
    rewrite ^ $scheme://www.DOMAIN.COM$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 default ssl;
    #ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl.key;

    server_name www.DOMAIN.COM;
    # most likely /var/www/...
    root /path/to/files;

    include /etc/nginx/restrictions.conf;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$") {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    # protect directories
    location /app/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /includes/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /lib/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /lib/minify/ {
        allow all;
    }
    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /pkginfo/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /report/config.xml {
        deny all;
    }
    location /var/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /var/export/ {
        # restrict access to admins
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$1 last;
    }

    # include php specific configuration
    include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
}
```

This is a php-fpm specific configuration file which intercepts error codes and splits the path info correctly so you have access to the correct path parts in PHP. I also use a Unix socket rather than a port due to performance improvements. Also note that you don't need to repeat the fastcgi_params already specified in fastcgi_params.

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

# this will allow Nginx to intercept 4xx/5xx error codes
# Nginx will only intercept if there are error page rules defined
# -- This is better placed in the http {} block as a default
# -- in that virtual host's server block

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # A handy function that became available in 0.7.31 that breaks down 
    # The path information based on the provided regex expression
    # This is handy for requests such as file.php/some/paths/here/ 

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/phpfpm.sock;
}
```

My fastcgi_params configuration file is optimized for a small server (<1GB RAM). Be sure to adjust yours according to your server's performance:

```
fastcgi_param    QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param    REQUEST_METHOD        $request_method;
fastcgi_param    CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param    CONTENT_LENGTH        $content_length;

fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param    REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_ROOT        $document_root;
fastcgi_param    SERVER_PROTOCOL        $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param    GATEWAY_INTERFACE    CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param    SERVER_SOFTWARE        nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param    REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param    REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param    SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param    SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param    SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param    REDIRECT_STATUS        200;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 90;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 360;
fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 512k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 1024k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_pass_header *;
```

Answer (score 5):

We have magento installed to mydomain.com/store, and we use next config for nginx:

```
server {
    listen          <needed ip(s)>:80;
    server_name     mydomain.com;
    root            /www/mydomain;

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }


    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           30d;
    }

    location /store/ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/store/index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME /store/index.php;

        fastcgi_index   index.php;
    }

    location /store/static/ { }
    location /store/skin/ { }
    location /store/media/ { }

    location /store/errors/ { }

    location ~* /store/errors/.*\.xml$ { deny all; }
    location ~* /store/errors/.*\.phtml$ { deny all; }
    location ~* /store/errors/.*\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME /store/errors$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }

    location /store/js/ { }

    location ~* /store/js/.*\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/store/js$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME /store/js$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to rewrite all .htaccess rules to ngnix configuration to get this working. Worth to read http://www.nbs-system.co.uk/blog-2/magento-optimization-howto-en.html